# webrequest timeout downloading large image files

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, timeoutexception

Getting a webrequest timeout when trying to download large video files through WebDAM's (a third party content management system) API.  Here is the basic code that is used to get the video.

```
public void StreamAsset(String AssetID, HttpResponse Response)
    {

            WebRequest request = request = WebRequest.Create(_api_url_v2 + "assets/" + AssetID + "/download");
            request.Timeout = 200000;
            // add OAuth header
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _access_token);

            // get response from WebDAM web service
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream file = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                Int32 bytesRead = 0;
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[524000];

                while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    else
                        break;
                }
                file.Close();
            }

        }


    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this code or do I just have to jack up the timeout property.

I get the pretty standard following error.

Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the httpRuntime timeout in your Web.config file like below...

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="n"/>
</system.web>
```

...where n is the number of seconds that your request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.